# Floating point numbers... dar nu-mă, nu-mă iei!

Tags: code-golf, number

When you leave, my challenges fade to grey, 0A0AE<sub>16</sub>, 0A0A0AE<sub>16</sub>...

A while ago, I made this programming language (https://esolangs.org/wiki/Dragostea_din_tei) which uses an interesting number system. It is base two for integers, but for decimals it divides a base two integer by a power of ten.

The input should be a floating point number, negative, positive or zero.

The output should be "the" standard representation for, that number, in the programming language, which should follow these steps:

1. Start with the absolute value of that number.
   Now multiply the result by the smallest power of ten to make it an integer (for example, 123.45 -> multiply by 100 to make 12345) and call it *a*.
2. Write `Ma-ia hii` + a newline (literally, push the number zero).
3. Write *a* in base two, with `Ma-ia huu` + a newline for ones, and `Ma-ia hoo` + a newline for 0's.
4. Now, if the original number (not *a*) has any decimal places, write `Ma-ia haha` + a newline for every digit after the decimal point, for example twice for 123.45.
5. If the original number is negative, write `Vrei sa pleci dar`.

You can add or omit trailing and leading newlines if you want.

DONE. Now, here are some good ol' examples:
-10 is:

```
Ma-ia hii
Ma-ia huu
Ma-ia hoo
Ma-ia huu
Ma-ia hoo
Vrei sa pleci dar
```

256 is:

```
Ma-ia hii
Ma-ia huu
Ma-ia hoo
Ma-ia hoo
Ma-ia hoo
Ma-ia hoo
Ma-ia hoo
Ma-ia hoo
Ma-ia hoo
Ma-ia hoo
```

And 3.14 is:

```
Ma-ia hii
Ma-ia huu
Ma-ia hoo
Ma-ia hoo
Ma-ia huu
Ma-ia huu
Ma-ia huu
Ma-ia hoo
Ma-ia huu
Ma-ia hoo
Ma-ia haha
Ma-ia haha
```

And finally for -3.14:

```
Ma-ia hii
Ma-ia huu
Ma-ia hoo
Ma-ia hoo
Ma-ia huu
Ma-ia huu
Ma-ia huu
Ma-ia hoo
Ma-ia huu
Ma-ia hoo
Ma-ia haha
Ma-ia haha
Vrei sa pleci dar
```

This is code-golf, so fewest bytes wins!

Comment: Is it okay if it ends up outputting the representation of `3.14000000000000012` for `3.14`. Floating point representation nonsense. :P

Comment: @totallyhuman Yes.

Comment: O-Zone have a lot to answer for, but a programming language was not on my bingo card for 2024.

Comment: Consider adding a negative test case with decimals e.g. `-3.14`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>65</s> 59 bytes

```
⁺Ma-ia h⁺×²⁺⟦i⟧Ｅ↨ＩΦθ‹.ι²§ouιＥΦθ№…θκ.¦aha¿№θ-”(/◧êºcS﹪Ｚ↑Ｍ▶#↓
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY4xC8JADIV3f0XIlEJbsLp10oIgWOggLuIQ2pMGz7betaK//ryzgkOG9/K9l9Qtm7pn7VxlpBup0pMlLDkRhhZj@Oqj3JWl7KfOKHiJoeSBtmwVFWxH2okelaFHDAdlfUPqsxJFMWR@NuO@a9SLsJ9mOyxC/p8q@slfL961VkXbD8G6ecj3BBa5ZQyxfCFXoBn2CCbehflzPBklYBkGrWqBhg1GuXOrdLl2yVN/AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⁺Ma-ia h⁺×²⁺⟦i⟧Ｅ↨ＩΦθ‹.ι²§ouιＥΦθ№…θκ.¦aha
```

Remove non-digits from the input, convert from base `10` to base `2`, and replace `0`s with `o` and `1`s with `u`. Prefix `i` to the resulting list, then double the letters. Append `aha` to the list for each digit after the `.` (if any), prepend `Ma-ia h` to each element of the list, and output the result.

```
¿№θ-”(/◧êºcS﹪Ｚ↑Ｍ▶#↓
```

If the input contained a `-` then output `Vrei sa pleci dar` using a compressed string.

If an extra `Ma-ia hoo` is acceptable for an input of `0`, then for 55 bytes:

```
⁺Ma-ia h⁺×²⪪⁺i⍘ＩΦθ‹.ιou¹ＥΦθ№…θκ.¦aha¿№θ-”(/◧êºcS﹪Ｚ↑Ｍ▶#↓
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY-xCsJADIZ3nyJkuoO2qJPgZsFJQVBcxCGepw2ett5dBZ_FRUHRt3H2bbxaBZckf_L9JDk9VEZW5WTO51vpV3Hn9RxZ3nkxMqUTOKSYCTKM4KMnvNVOtCMYF4Z_DIdpj5we-2Bci5ScF302Xluxj2CgXWCSwLCUEWBeYpVbVRhS8UemeRn2pkdldJrlRdXaVI7kY0DKKBRSdhu8AlHDAcE4dKG-GadWMziCwmjFsCSLsnt1C-W-z91nGB8Mzi_NWr8B) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: When converting `0` to a string base the version of Charcoal on TIO always returns `0` but the version of Charcoal on ATO returns the first character of the string. (For a numeric base conversion both versions would return an empty list.)

Comment: The 55-byte answer is valid.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 103 bytes

Recursively builds the output from bottom to top.

```javascript
f=x=>x<0?f(-x)+`
Vrei sa pleci dar`:x%1?f(x*10)+m+`aha`:x?f(x>>1)+m+(x&1?`uu`:`oo`):(m=`
Ma-ia h`)+`ii`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc29DoMgGIXhnatgaQMlGunfYCpeQdfO3xfESoNisDbcPcWx6fqc5D0v/OCig53fxeQ7k1LfxEbFW9X2rIhcAHkEY@mCdHZGW9phgDruZJ7jQVZcjAJwwGybKCU3YXEvW1hXqMF74DUbGyB3LCzSAXLTWkjaT4t3pnT@yfJVTnHya8fL9c9OpTxznr4)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>194</s> <s>189</s> <s>186</s> <s>172</s> 171 bytes

```python
def f(i):d=max(0,f"{i:g}"[::-1].find('.'));*map(print,["Ma-ia h"+x for x in["ii"]+["uo"[b<"1"]*2for b in f"{int(abs(i)*10**d):b}"]+["aha"]*d]+["Vrei sa pleci dar"]*(i<0)),
```

*-3 bytes thanx to Neil*

I expect some fancy recursive method to make it below 100 bytes.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY6_TsMwEMb3PMXJS-00iZLyR8i0IyMbYok6OLVNTqSO5TgiFeqTsGSBBV6It8FJGDp9393v7rv7-LInX7dmHD97r9O732-pNGiKjMvdUQw0TzR5R_5yJiXnabHPNBpJV9mKsfv4KCy1Do1PSvIoUhRQk_UAunUwAJqSIJL9uiR9S8pqSwqyjzcTrAKEKdd4KqouXIuLPI4l49V5XhC1CLNyss9OIXQCbKMOCFK4AChuc8aS_5e7txobBU-uVzwC8O40STCq87AD3bTCUzS295Sxmcw_04kvtb7wC2NRKNRwUNbDwyzYmiW2ckq8LqfHn7TIo83NbXSVFddL7w8)

Comment: `p("uo"[b<"1"]*2)` saves 3 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-n`, 106 bytes

```perl
s/\.//;say"Ma-ia h$_"for ii,(oo,uu,aha)[(sprintf"%b%s",abs,$'=~y//2/cr)=~/./g];say"Vrei sa pleci dar"if/-/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcxBDoIwEADArzQNREjaLlU5GZ7A1Ysas2CBTQhtunDgwtOtifOACS7OdUoMTwNwY9xli5pQTNlbDj4KIlV4r7ZN4YTlo@AQaVkHmXc5S4Udq@zUHDvAGfpYNgcYGF//5x4dCUYRZteT@GCUNICGlC7GXm399WElv3DSbW0qWyW9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 104 bytes

```
-(.+)
$1Vrei sa pleci dar¶
\.(.+)
$1$.1$*h
h
aha
\d+
ii$&$*
+`(1+)\1
$1oo
o?o?1
uu
\Ga?[a-z].
Ma-ia h$&¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lcq9DsIgFAbQ/XsKBmxoCcTr38rYydVFTHpjSSBpxKBdfLA@QF8MHZzPKeGdHlw3qh@qUVa3kHQpIYkXi@cU7kmMXNYF3v5RWpJdRARHhh81UpKN7KAHRbr19Cs5I7vsCPMM37O7svncLM5sEosom3Wp1dAWu@MJe0uHLw) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
-(.+)
$1Vrei sa pleci dar¶
```

Handle negative numbers.

```
\.(.+)
$1$.1$*h
h
aha
```

Handle decimals.

```
\d+
ii$&$*
+`(1+)\1
$1oo
o?o?1
uu
```

Convert to unary, but using `oo` and `uu` instead of `0` and `1`, and prefixing `ii`.

```
\Ga?[a-z].
Ma-ia h$&¶
```

Expand `ii`, `oo`, `uu` and `aha` to the full text.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 145 bytes

```powershell
filter f{$q="Ma-ia h"
if($_-lt0){-$_|f
"Vrei sa pleci dar"}elseif($_%1){$_*10|f
$q+'aha'}elseif($_){$_-shr1|f
$q+('oo','uu')[$_%2]}else{$q+"ii"}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3NCsMgEITvPoWIxaTplpj@3PoIvfZSSpBUURBMNKGHNM9uExPoYRdmvtnZ1n2kD1paC43zMkZlbC89ViPtbuQuwAisCTIqozXYvsxHoPVXIfLw0uAgcGtlY/BbeDJJG2QK7ng@0nrPyzlIu4IJLdifLgyC9nylGXOOHdgwsPw5n1avlJzfF8QYMk0ReIkgdSFCUHW5LrOp05Gf09o0JANWJ/4A)

A recursive filter

[Non recursive](https://tio.run/##PU3LbsIwELz7K6zVQmKMKxxaLpU/gSsXxGFFHcVSkIMN4pD624NjWi47j53ZHfzDhtjZvldnH@yErRmngQJdaiRR49XAnpQj3oGQ4Bww1@aN6m8bMWI0azgE63gkPvT27PgPBWBIRiGl1of6G2mh8zBIK10qMndwvCbqCP4jr4CKXdB/kfxZ1pX31bq63ytxzGeak0gYfxc5cFRSojulKTGm9IYtseUzMgDWfO2KnnHW2w/9WYxCZke9rcKmJw)

```powershell
param($a) # input in variable $a
($q="Ma-ia h")+"ii" # output Ma-ia hii and store `Ma-ia h` in a variable
if($a-lt0){$s=,"Vrei sa pleci dar";$a=-$a} # if $a is negative, make it positive and initialise the list of output with Vrei sa pleci dar
for(;$a%1;$a=$a*10){$s+=,"${q}aha"} # while $a has decimals, multiply it by 10 and add Ma-ia haha to the list of output
for(;$a;$a=$a-shr1){$s+=,($q+('oo','uu')[$a%2])} # convert $a to binary and for each bit, append either Ma-ia hoo or Ma-ia huu to the list of output
$s|%{$s[-++$i]}  # reverse and print the list of output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 56 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
þ„ouÅв'išºI'.¡¦Jg…ahaи«"Ma-ia h"ì.•1Ć¹bWÖYþï§{•.ªIDÄÊи«»
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AWUAmv9vc2FiaWX//8O@4oCeb3XDhdCyJ2nFocK6SScuwqHCpkpn4oCmYWhh0LjCqyJNYS1pYSBoIsOsLuKAojHEhsK5YlfDllnDvsOvwqd74oCiLsKqSUTDhMOK0LjCq8K7//8tMy4xNA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpipaBkX6nDpeRfWgLh6VT@P7zvUcO8/NLDrRc2qWceXXhoV6W63qGFh5Z5pT9qWJaYkXhhx6HVSr6JupmJChlKh9foPWpYZHik7dDOpPDD0yIP7zu8/tDyaqCY3qFVlS6HWw53gdQf2v1f59A2@//RuoYGOkamZjrGeoYmOrpg0tDIWM/ENBYA).

**Explanation:**

```python
þ                      # Only leave the digits of the (implicit) input-number
 „ouÅв                 # Convert it to custom base-"ou", which will basically converts
                       # to base-2, and indexes the result into "ou"
      'iš             '# Prepend an "i"
         º             # Double each character in the list
I'.¡                  '# Push the input again, and split it on "."
    ¦                  # Remove the first item
     Jg                # Take the length of what remains
       …ahaи           # Repeat "aha" that many times as list
            «          # Merge it to the earlier list
"Ma-ia h"ì             # Prepend "Ma-ia h" before each string in the list
.•1Ć¹bWÖYþï§{•         # Push compressed string "vrei sa pleci dar"
              .ª       # Sentence capitalize the leading "V"
                ID     # Push two copies of the input
                  Ä    # Take the absolute value of the copy
                   Ê   # Pop both, and check whether they are NOT equal
                       # (aka 1 if the input is negative; 0 otherwise)
                    и  # Repeat "Vrei sa pleci dar" that many times as list
                     « # Merge this to the list as well
»                      # Join the list with newline delimiter
                       # (after which the multiline string is output implicitly as result)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress strings not part of the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `.•1Ć¹bWÖYþï§{•` is `"vrei sa pleci dar"`.